# How should we respond to dead links?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I saw [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/179531) containing a dead link to a website with lots of ads that does not redirect (I used a redirect tracker. So how can we alert the mods to delete it?

Comment: Looks like the answer is gone already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag as spam or for moderator attention.

With enough spam flags a post is deleted without a moderator intervention.

You can find more info on this [Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/?cb=1), aptly advertised on the right of the screen as I am writing this answer.

Comment: I find that a bit harsh. It may be that the post is not really spammy, but rather honest links died. Won't the post author be penalized by the system if they receive too many such flags?

Comment: On this we'd have to be careful because not all dead links are spam! If folks just flag a dead link answer as spam, you might up automatically deleting a top / green check mark answer! Editing the links is a better option.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to edit the post, and either remove the spam links completely or replace with a better link.

Eg, links to ebay expire after a while, so grab a useful image and insert that instead.

If it is a dead link, then you can check if the page was archived at the wayback machine, or find another URL that serves the same purpose.